# Appointments created in OWA show up in Outlook with "None" listed as the end time

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-web-app, calendar

Environment: Exchange 2003 SP2, Outlook 2007/2010 (with latest service packs)

When a user creates an appointment in OWA (specifying a start and end time), the appointment appears in Outlook incorrectly. In Outlook, the appointment appears at the top of the calendar in the area for all day appointments. When you hover over the appointment the text displayed shows Start time-None "Appointment Subject" (i.e. 10:00am-None Test Appointment).

If you double click on the appointment the start and end time are listed correctly. If you click Save and Close, nothing changes, the appointment is still listed at the top in the all day appointment section.

This issue goes away if you switch the Outlook profile to NOT use Cached Mode. However, this isn't an acceptable fix for all users.

This is happening for all users. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Checked for updates on the Exchange server, there are no updates related to Exchange.
- Recreated the Outlook profile.
- Turned Cached Mode off then back on.
- Cleared Offline Items for the Calendar in Outlook.
- Ran Outlook with switches (cleanreminders, resetfolders).
- Reset IIS on the Exchange server.

The only information I could find related to this issue on the internet pointed to an issue with Outlook 2003 pre-SP3. I have confirmed that I'm experiencing my issue on Outlook 2007 AND Outlook 2010 clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our resolution to the issue was as follows:

Install hotfixes to update the following files to the noted versions:

MasSync.dll
6.5.7655.0

Davex.dll
6.5.7655.10

Also uninstalled Outlook 2007 client from the Exchange server.

After these steps and a reboot, the issue is resolved, and creating a calendar appointment in OWA now syncs correctly to Outlook.

Hopefully this will help someone else.